# how to interface xenserver and ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, interface, xen

i install xenserver hypervisor in 1st laptop and in 2nd laptop i installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS with openstack using devstack installation. Now i want to interface this 2 laptops. how to interface between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's your goal there but normally you'd install Xenserver to manage virtual machines inside the same server (on its most basic config).

You can also have server pools with extra hardware in different locations, aka your laptop. In that scenario you sitll have to install Xen software and configure them to work together.

In the case you are describing sounds like you are using your laptop as a regular ubuntu machine.